# A continuous area-preserving mapping is an isometry?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Suppose that $f\colon\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ is a continuous map which preserves area in the Euclidean sense. Can we say that $f$ is an isometry?

Note. We donot assume that $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: Try $f$ linear with determinant $1$.

Comment: @Avatar, the MO question is interesting, but not directly relevant, is it?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: i understood your point,sorry; i am deleting my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

consider the matrix $$A =  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
2 &0  \\
0 & 1/2 \\
 \end{array} \right) $$ and the continuous function $y=Ax$.

The area of any set remains the same under this linear transformation, but $|A \hat{x}| = 2 > 1. $

Comment: There's an echo in here.